# Storing lists of objects in SQLite

Tags: c#, sql, xamarin, sqlite, xamarin.forms

Learning SQLite here..

In my app I have the below Team class. 
Bill, User, and Payment are other object classes. 
Most things works in the app, but I can not retrieve the list of Users, Bills or Payment. No exceptions are thrown, but the ListViews appear blank. Am I doing this right? note that the list of Teams appears on the main page no issues.

```
public class Team
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<User> Members = new List<User>();
    public List<Bill> Bills = new List<Bill>();
    public List<Payment> Payments = new List<Payment>();

    public Club()
    {         
    }
    public Club(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Code to display is here:

```
    private Team _team;
    private SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;


    public TeamPage(Team team)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        _team = team;
        try
        {
            Title = _team.Name;
            TeamBills.ItemsSource = _team.Bills;
            TeamPayments.ItemsSource = _team.Payments;
            UserList.ItemsSource = _team.Members.ToList();
            teamBills.HeightRequest = team.Bills.Count * 50;
            teamPayments.HeightRequest = team.Payments.Count * 50;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", "something happnened in list displays","ok");
        }

        _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>().GetConnection();
    }
```

Main page code to pass the team object:

```
async void MyTeams_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        Team selectedTeam;

        if (e.Item as Team == null)
            await DisplayAlert("Team error", "team selected is null!?", "ok");
        else
        {
           selectedTeam = e.Item as Team;
           await Navigation.PushAsync(new TeamPage(selectedTeam));
           ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }
```

Where _team is added (this is from a different page):

```
async void Finished_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _newTeam.Members.AddRange(NewMembers);
        _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>().GetConnection();
        await _connection.InsertAsync(_newTeam);
        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "NewTeamAdded", _newTeam);
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyTeamPage());
    }
```

Comment: Hi, could you please post the code you use to retrieve the Users? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, christos for looking, edited the questions

Comment: You are welcome. From the code you have posted I don't see any attempt to connect to the database or to retrieve any data. In the constructor of `TeamPage` class you pass a reference to an object of type `Team`. If for instance the `team` you pass has been created as `Team team = new Team();` it is logically that you have noted.

Comment: I've added above how it is passed, the data is created in the app manually and before implementing Sqlite it was working.. Is sqlite supposed to be able to save the properties and the list properties in one table?

Comment: Since I am not familiar at all with xamarin, I searched about `Navigation.PushAsync`, despite the fact it seems to me that this method hasn't to do anything with sqlite or any other db. So I verified my assumption. Furthermore, I would say again that there isn't any code where you open a connection to the database and you try to do something (like inserting some data or retieve some other data etc.) Regarding your question I don't think that SQLite would select by its own how to persit the data you have in your UI. You have to define the tables and insert there the corresponding data.

Comment: ok thanks Christos, added the code from the editor page where the team is added to the database. I think you might be right, this is not related to db issue but something I am missing but have no clue what...

Comment: You need to create Tables for each entity in your db (User, Bill, Payment) not just Team.  Then you use [SQLite Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) to model the relations between them.

Comment: Thanks again Jason, exactly what I need.